# orange border on focus of jquery ui lightness buttons and textboxes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am  using Jquery UI in my asp.net application and using jquery ui dialog. I have customized its Lightness theme css. I have made background black and some other things. Now I see that when some text box or button has focus, it gets orange color border. I want to remove that or change to black.

Can you please suggest me which class do I need to change?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably the default outline. Set `outline: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

if you show your code you can get clear answer..

for example .. if there is any error this class will add to the element..

```
.ui-state-error {
     border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
    }
```

so changing this color will help there.. in the same way you can solve your problem